# How to determine from within Java which .NET framework is installed

Tags: java, .net-3.5

From within my Java program I want to determine which .NET Framework is installed on the system. What is the best (and easiest) way to do this?

**Answer** Thanks scubabbl! It worked to check the directory `System.getenv( "WINDIR" ) + "\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework"` for its directories starting with the letter "v".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, the actual file structure in c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework has folders with versions of .Net installed. On my computer, I have folders up to v3.5, or 
c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5.

There are lots of issues with this, including security issues though.

The second, and probably better answer would be to check the windows registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP

The Version key will have the value you are looking for.

Edit: stackoverflow question regarding reading the registry with java.
[read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/readwrite-to-windows-registry-using-java)

This library http://www.trustice.com/java/jnireg/ will allow you to read the registry.

Comment: Thanks! Checking that directory should do the trick for me, since I know I have read access. one additional tweak is to use System.getenv("WINDIR") in case someone installed Windows in D: or somewhere exotic.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the directory structure is not the best way to do this. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080/how-to-detect-what-net-framework-versions-and-service-packs-are-installed) for the full details on the registry keys you need to evaluate.